# How should I handle exceptions within a controller constructor in WebAPI?

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.5

Say I have a constructor where it's initialization can potentially throw an exception due to reasons beyond my control.

```
FantasticApiController(IAwesomeGenerator awesome,
    IBusinessRepository repository, IIceCreamFactory factory)
{
       Awesome = awesome;
       Repository = repository;
       IceCream = factory.MakeIceCream();

       DoSomeInitialization(); // this can throw an exception
}
```

Ordinarily, when a Controller action in WebAPI throws an exception I can handle it via  a csutom `ExceptionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class CustomErrorHandler
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Critical error, this is real bad.
        if (context.Exception is BubonicPlagueException)
        {
            Log.Error(context.Exception, "CLOSE EVERYTHING!");
            Madagascar.ShutdownAllPorts();
        }

        // No big deal, just show something user friendly
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Hey something bad happened. " +
                                        "Not closing the ports though"),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        });
    }
```

So if I have a have a `BoardPlane` API method which throws a `BubonicPlagueException`, then my `CustomerErrorHandler` will shut down the ports to Madagascar and log it as an error as expected. In other instances when it's not really serious, I just display some user friendly message and return a 500 `InternalServerError`.

But in those cases where `DoSomeInitialization` throws an exception, this does absolutely nothing. **How can I handle exceptions in WebAPI controller constructors?**

Comment: One interesting feature of WebApi is that you can customize easily the way the exception is returned to the client. Status and Html error within the same action method. Obviously you loose all this if  exception is thrown within the constructor. I think you should avoid this happen. Most of the logic should be put in the webapi method not in the constructor. That said I think you should use the standard asp.net error handling, that is configuring error pages within the Web.Config, or intercepting the onerror event in the global asax

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The WebApi Controllers are created, and thus constructors called via HttpControllerActivators. The default activator is System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.

Very rough examples for options 1 & 2 on github here https://github.com/markyjones/StackOverflow/tree/master/ControllerExceptionHandling/src

**Option 1** which works quite nicely involves the use of a DI container (you may well be using one already). I have used Ninject for my example and have used "Interceptors" [Read More](http://innovatian.com/2010/03/using-ninject-extensions-interception-part-1-the-basics/) to intercept and try/catch calls to the Create method on the DefaultHttpControllerActivator. I know of at least AutoFac and Ninject that can do something simlar to to the following:

*Create the interceptor*

I don't know what the lifetime scope of your Madagascar and Log items are but they could well be injected into your Interceptor

```
public class ControllerCreationInterceptor : Ninject.Extensions.Interception.IInterceptor
{
    private ILog _log;
    private IMadagascar _madagascar;

    public ControllerCreationInterceptor(ILog log, IMadagascar madagascar)
    {
        _log = log;
        _madagascar = madagascar;
    }
```

But keeping to the example in your question where Log and Madagascar are some kind of Static global

```
public class ControllerCreationInterceptor : Ninject.Extensions.Interception.IInterceptor
{

    public void Intercept(Ninject.Extensions.Interception.IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            if (e.InnerException is BubonicPlagueException)
            {
                Log.Error(e.InnerException, "CLOSE EVERYTHING!");
                Madagascar.ShutdownAllPorts();
                //DO SOMETHING WITH THE ORIGIONAL ERROR!
            }
            //DO SOMETHING WITH THE ORIGIONAL ERROR!
        }
    }
}
```

*FINALLY Register the interceptor* In global asax or App_Start (NinjectWebCommon)

```
kernel.Bind<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator>()
            .To<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator>().Intercept().With<ControllerCreationInterceptor>();
```

**Option 2** is to implement your own Controller Activator implementing the IHttpControllerActivator interface and handle the error in creation of the Controller in the Create method. You could use the decorator pattern to wrap the DefaultHttpControllerActivator:

```
public class YourCustomControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IHttpControllerActivator _default = new DefaultHttpControllerActivator();

    public YourCustomControllerActivator()
    {

    }

     public System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController Create(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _default.Create(request, controllerDescriptor, controllerType);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            if (e.InnerException is BubonicPlagueException)
            {
                Log.Error(e.InnerException, "CLOSE EVERYTHING!");
                Madagascar.ShutdownAllPorts();
                //DO SOMETHING WITH THE ORIGIONAL ERROR!
            }
            //DO SOMETHING WITH THE ORIGIONAL ERROR!
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Once you have your own custom activator the default activator can be [switched out](http://lucid-nonsense.co.uk/dependency-injection-web-api-and-mvc-4-rc/) in the global asax :

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new YourCustomControllerActivator());
```

**Option 3** Of course if your initialisation in the constructor doesn't need access to the actual Controllers methods, properties etc... i.e. assuming it could be removed from the constructor... then it would be far easier to just move the initialisation to a filter  e.g.

```
public class MadagascarFilter : AbstractActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
    try{
          DoSomeInitialization(); // this can throw an exception
        }
        catch(BubonicPlagueException e){
    Log.Error(e, "CLOSE EVERYTHING!");
        Madagascar.ShutdownAllPorts();
            //DO SOMETHING WITH THE ERROR                           
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }

    public override bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }


}
```